# Add a document to a non-existent subcollection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Hope this isn't too obvious but I am really stumped at this point.  I am having trouble adding a document to a subcollection that does not exist in Firebase Firestore.

The code works perfectly when adding to a subcollection that already exists.

```
db.collection("collectionId").doc(docId).collection("subcollectionId").doc(subdocId).collection("items").add({
    userName,
    isActive: true        
}).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

To be clear here, the sub-sub-collection "items" exists in some of my sub-collections and has not yet been created in others.  When I attempt to add a document to "items" using the above code in a subcollection that already has other "items", it works with the following result:

```
Document successfully written!
```

When I attempt to add a document to "items" in a subcollection where "items" does not exist, it does not add the item and there is nothing written to the console.

Thanks for the help in advance!

**UPDATE WITH SCREENSHOTS AS ASKED FOR:**

Success:
[image]

Failure:
[image]

Comment: Can you share some screenshots of your Firebase/Cloud console, showing exactly where you shoudl see new docs and subcollections?

Answer (score 2):

When you write a document to any collection or subcollection that doesn't exist, it will then immediately exist.  This behavior never changes.  The SDK will never give you an indicator of success without actually writing the document.

If you're saying that the document just doesn't get written, then it sounds like you're not looking in the right place.  Refreshing the Firebase or Cloud console in your web browser helps to reveal newly created collections.  It will also help if you know exactly what the value of `subdocId` is here, so you know for sure where to look.

Comment: I refreshed the cloud console within the browser as well as my own website that reads the database and no new document (or new subcollection) appear there.  I do want to clarify that I only get the success indicator when successfully adding a new doc to an existing subcollection.  I get no indicator when unsuccessfully adding a new doc to a new subcollection.